# Trying to understand a simple open() in a linux driver

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

In a simple Linux device driver code, I found the following function:

```
static int my_open(struct inode *i, struct file *f)   
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: open()\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This is taken from [here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/04/character-device-files-creation-operations/).

Can someone explain me what do we mean by `inode` here and why is this function `static`?

Answer (score 1):

The function is `static` since the writer didn't want the function to be visible from outside the driver's code, i.e. you can't link against it directly. It's very likely exposed through some `init()` function which puts the function pointer in a table of "methods", if I recall how Linux drivers tend to look.

The [`struct inode`](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch12lev1sec6) value describes a file or directory on disk.